# remove asp:View from asp:MultiView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following part of code:

```
 <tb:Tabs ID="Tabs" runat="server" />
            <asp:MultiView ID="MV" runat="server">
                <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                    <div class="results">
                        DO STH
                 </div>
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                    <div class="results">
                       ...
                        DO STH
                    </div>
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
                    <div class="results">
                        ...
                        DO STH
                    </div>
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="View4" runat="server">
                    <div class="results" >
                       ...
                       DO STH
                    </div>
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="View5" runat="server">
                    <div class="results">
                       DO STH
                    </div>
                </asp:View>



            </asp:MultiView>
```

and I want to remove from code behind the asp:View3 under some conditions.

So, I am trying with the following code:

```
 if(condition)
 MV.Vies.Remove(View3);
```

and this is disappears, but when I am trying to click on the last Tab "View4", i get in VS the following error:

```
Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the      control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.
```

Does anybody can help me understand why does it happen and how can I solve it?Thx

Comment: In which event do you remove the view?